# Characters above header appearing on Avada theme WP site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I’m building a wordpress site using the latest version of the Avada theme. My support license is expired so I’m hoping there are a couple knowledgeable folks here that can help.

I started building out the site and configuring my header first. All of a sudden I’m getting one line of text containing letters “ere” with a white background. This is appearing above my header on all pages. Any ideas on where/how to locate and remove this issue?

Thanks in advance for the help!

I’ve gone back through the Avada global options, header options, and header components but nothing obvious is showing. I also looked at the header.php file under Avada too but nothing with the letters “ere” are showing up. I have cleared cache too. Thanks

Comment: Can you add a link to the site?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you managed to resolve this but just in case you haven't, this was how I resolved a similar issue.

I made sure all platforms were updated and changed my header layout style. Logged out and logged back in and it resolved itself. I then changed my header style back and continued setting up the website.

I hope this helps.